# having a problem in json file to find arguman

Tags: javascript, python, json

This is my JSON file and I have error can anyone correct this?
I don't know where is the problem between my blocks, for reading 
I use jsonpathfinder but it gives me a syntax error.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "gender": "male"
    }
  ]
}{
  "data": [
    {
      "firstName": "Amir",
      "lastName": "Marezloo",
      "birthDate": "11/02/1998",
      "bloodType": "O+"
    }
  ]
}{
  "data": [
    {
      "country": "Iran",
      "province": "Golestan",
      "city": "Gorgan"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: pls post the code where you try to parse this json. It makes also not really sense to set the same attribute multiple times. And last but not least this is not a valid json.

Comment: missing comma ( , ) between data objects and everything must be inside list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JSON` has Multiple root elements!

in :

[Code 22, Structure 11]

[Code 22, Structure 34]

Your valid JSON is :

```
[{
  "data": [
    {
      "gender": "male"
    }
  ]
},{
  "data": [
    {
      "firstName": "Amir",
      "lastName": "Marezloo",
      "birthDate": "11/02/1998",
      "bloodType": "O+"
    }
  ]
},{
  "data": [
    {
      "country": "Iran",
      "province": "Golestan",
      "city": "Gorgan"
    }
  ]
}]
```